# Parse Json with GSON to ObservableField

Tags: android, gson, pojo, android-databinding

I tried to parse a JSON Result to my POJO class with GSON.

When my POJO looks like

```
public class Content {
    public String name;
    public String shortDescription;
}
```

I can do successfully this, to have my Json Data in c1.name and c1.shortDescription:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();

Content c1 = gson.fromJson(contentSt, Content.class);
```

But when my POJO looks like

```
public class Content {
    public ObservableField<String> name= new ObservableField<String>();
    public ObservableField<String> shortDescription = new ObservableField<String>(); 
}
```

I got this error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 151 path $.shortDescription
```

Any advice how to solve this? I'm very glad for any help and thanks for reading my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You better use a POJO and extends from BaseObservable at the moment. It is another approach to achieve two way databinding. Reference: [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#observable_objects)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `TypeAdapter` in GSON?
You can transform fields values from an object to JSON format, for example:

```
val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
gsonBuilder.setTypeAdapter(Any::class, object : TypeAdapter<*>() {
    ...
    override fun write(`in`: Any, `out`: JSONWriter) {
        // your transform code here, for example:
        if (`in`.observableFieldItem is ModelHasObservableFields) {
            `out`.observableFieldItem = `in`.observableFieldItem.get()
        }
    }
    ...
})
```

Above is example that remember, it may be incorrect syntax, but you can reference this link: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/
Hope it help!